# i'm not able to understand this even if i return the value for base condition

Tags: python, function, recursion

i tried to solve sum of digits using recursion but it's throwing nonetype error

```
def sumofdigits(n):
    if n>=0 and int(n)==n:
        if n==0:
            return 0
        else:
            return (n%10)+sumofdigits((n/10))
print(sumofdigits(113))
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-b6ff967381e6> in <module>
      6         else:
      7             return (n%10)+sumofdigits((n/10))
----> 8 print(sumofdigits(113))
      9 

<ipython-input-132-b6ff967381e6> in sumofdigits(n)
      5             return 0
      6         else:
----> 7             return (n%10)+sumofdigits((n/10))
      8 print(sumofdigits(113))
      9 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

this is the error which i got
can anyone please explain this

Comment: Is there any way in which `sumofdigits` will return `None`? (Hint: yes)

Comment: Use `n // 10`, not `n / 10`. This is both correct and eliminates the need to check if `int(n) == n`, since you won't be passing a `float` incorrectly as an argument.

Comment: no if i use int before n program is giving desired output

Comment: Also, use `q, r = divmod(n, 10)` to get both values at once, then return `r + sum_of_digits(q)`.

Comment: More hints: When will `if n>=0 and int(n)==n` not be true?

Comment: @chepner thanks i got this

Comment: okay okay @chepner

Answer (score 1):

Using `n / 10` produces a floating point value, which if you pass to `sumofdigits` makes `int(n) == n` false, leading to your recursive call returning `None`.

Use `n // 10` instead to get the correct integer quotient. Now you don't need to check if `int(n) == n`. Further, unless you pass an negative number, `n // 10` will never be negative. You can eliminate the entire conditional that could result in `sumofdigits` implicitly returning `None`.

```
def sumofdigits(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (n%10)+sumofdigits((n//10))
```

You can also use `divmod` to get the both the quotient and the remainder in one operation, rather than using `%` and `//` separately.

```
def sumofdigits(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        q, r = divmod(n, 10)
        return r + sumofdigits(q)
```

---

(If you need to handle a negative argument, I'd add something like

```
if n < 0:
    return sumofdigits(-n)
```

to the beginning of the function.
)

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner has mentioned the problem is the n/10 instead of n//10. This leads to 113 becoming 11.3 and then the if statement fails and so the function doesn't produce a return value aka None. And None added to your int produces the error.